# jQuery UI - droppable accept event function(event,ui)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to use a function in jQuery UI droppable `accept` event,

I am trying to call `ui.draggable` inside that function.

I want a value of data attribute from `ui.draggable`. but it says `ui` is not defined.

Any other way to access `ui.draggable`

**here is my code**

```
jQuery( "#dropable" ).droppable({
    activeClass: "active",
    accept:function(event, ui) {
        return ui.draggable.data('accept');
    },
    hoverClass: "hover",
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
        // my function
    }
});
```

**why I am doing this?**

`accept` event class was stored in dragged element, Like:

```
<a data-accept=".drop">This will be dragged</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#option-accept):

> **accept**
>
> Controls which draggable elements are accepted by the droppable.
>
> **Multiple types supported:**
>
> - **Selector**: A selector indicating which draggable elements are accepted.
> - **Function**: A function that will be called for each draggable on the page (passed as the first argument to the function). The function
>     must return `true` if the draggable should be accepted.

So the first argument to the `accept` callback is the element in question not an event and there is no second argument.

I think you want something more like this:

```
accept: function(el) {
    return $(el).is($(this).data('accept'));
}
```

That will only accept a draggable that matches the droppable's `data-accept` attribute.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/8jyhu/1/